# How to view or save an <IPython.core.display.Image object> using plain python (not ipython)?

Tags: python, image, ipython, dask

In the process of learning dask, I am trying to generate program graph visualizations using the "visualize" method/function. However, I am not working with a notebook. As far as I can tell, there is no way to have dask output these graphs to anything other than an IPython.core.display.Image object, which I don't know how to view in regular python. For various reasons it's impractical for me to run my code using IPython.

Is there any way to display these objects in a regular Python script/shell? Or at least, to save them to a standard image file on disk?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.visualize` method allows you to specify a filename to output to, and other parameters to be passed to dot/graphviz:

```
d.visualize(filename='dask.pdf')
```

produces a PDF file output instead of attempting an inline representation. Various other graphical formats are supported, such as PNG (although it may depend on how you installed graphviz).

You can also extract the image bytes from the Image instance

```
im = d.visualize()
open('output.png', 'wb').write(im.data)
```

which will be in PNG format (also given by `im.format`).

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if there's a way to save IPython.core.display.Image objects in general, i.e., not using the visualize filename kwarg? Although this does solve my specific issue.

Comment: The [object](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.display.html#IPython.display.Image) has attributed like `data` (some bytes), `format` and `filename` for various sources. Not sure which would be populated in this case.

Comment: "filename (unicode) – Path to a local file to load the data from. Images from a file are always embedded." This seems to indicate that the filename attribute is for loading rather than saving. Same goes for the others.

Comment: Yes, there are multiple way to make these images. It *could* be from a file, or it could be from a bunch of bytes.

Comment: Your edit is exactly what I was getting at in my first comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is another possible answer to the question. If you inspect a `IPython.core.display.Image` object called `img` you can see it has a `data` attribute which holds the image data as bytes. You may read and show that image with [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/), which for historic reasons has the import name PIL.

```py
import os
import PIL

# img as a <IPython.core.display.Image object>
pimg = PIL.Image.open(io.BytesIO(img.data))
pimg.show()
```

This shows the image in the [default application](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.show) of the system. This of course can be saved with the `PIL.Image.save()` method (here assuming png):

```
pimg.save('/path/to/some-file.png')
```

#### Documentation

- [PIL.Image.show()](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.show)
- [PIL.Image.save()](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.show)

#### Installing PIL

```
python -m pip install Pillow
```

If you have problems, refer to the [docs](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html#basic-installation).

#### Bonus tip for Dask

If you're trying to visualize what your `.compute()` does, you might want to add `optimize_graph=True` the `.visualize()` call, as that is the default for [`.compute()`](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/api.html#dask.compute), but *not default* for [`.visualize()`](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/api.html#dask.visualize). And then there's [`.dask.visualize()`](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/graphviz.html#visualize-the-high-level-graph) which creates a high level called dask-hlg.svg into the current directory.